# How to run two Start-Job and wait for their results?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a list of commands and I'm trying to invoke them using Start-Job each. Each command should return an array of objects. How do I wait on each command's array and combine them after all commands are done running? I am using PS 5.1

```
cmds = "Command-One", "Command-Two"

foreach cmd in cmds 
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { cmd }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example:

```sh
# Launch two jobs that each output two numbers, 
# collect all their output, and clean up once they terminate.
" 1, 2 ", " 3, 4 " | 
  ForEach-Object { Start-Job -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create($_)) } | 
    Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Note how the input command *strings* (designed to output two numbers each) must be converted to [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) via [`[scriptblock]::Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create) so that they can be passed to [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)'s `-ScriptBlock` parameter.

However, it is preferable and simpler to provide the commands as script block to begin with; using script-block *literals* (`{ ... }`):

```sh
{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } | 
  ForEach-Object { Start-Job $_ } | 
    Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

If you want to separate the timing of creating the jobs from waiting for their completion / collecting their output:

```sh
$jobs = { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } | ForEach-Object { Start-Job $_ } 
 
# ... perform other tasks

$jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

All variants launch two jobs and (directly or indirectly) pipe the job objects output by [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) to [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job), which collects their output (see bottom section for details):

- `-Wait` additionally waits for both jobs to complete, thereby ensuring that all job output has been received and output

  - Without `-Wait`, `Receive-Job` collects all output produced *so far*, and returns right away, so that multiple calls may be necessary; optionally, you can collect output without consuming it (`-Keep`).
- `-AutoRemoveJob` automatically cleans up the jobs afterwards, which by definition have terminated by then.

Note that there's also:

- [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) which performs waiting only, optionally for a given *state* (`-State`), and optionally with a *timeout* (`-Timeout`), necessitating a separate `Receive-Job` call to collect output.
- [`Remove-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-job) which removes jobs only, optionally including their forceful termination (`-Force`), if they haven't completed yet.

---

**How `Receive-Job` collects output:**

- Jobs never create direct output to the caller's console - all output, even to [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) *other* than the success stream, such as with [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) - are collected by `Receive-Job` and routed to the corresponding output streams of the caller.
- Objects emitted by jobs to the *success* output stream (i.e. *data* output) are *decorated with properties identifying the job of origin*:

  - Properties containing auto-generated GUIDs identifying the job.

    - `.RunspaceId`
    - `.PSSourceJobInstanceId` (only while the job is running, seeminlgy)
    - Both change on every invocation; note that the optional, self-chosen symbolic name you may pass to `Start-Job` via `-Name` is *not* reflected here, so there is no obvious way to correlate output objects with the job they came from - see below.
  - Two more properties that are primarily of interest in PowerShell's *remoting* (whose infrastructure background jobs partially use):

    - `.PSComputerName`: always `'localhost'` in background jobs
    - `.PSShowComputerName`: always `$false` in background jobs; a hint to the formatting system as to whether to show the value of the `.PSComputerName` property.

To illustrate the points above:

```sh
# This collects 42 in $dataOutput, and prints
# 'Some status message' to the display; you could suppress that with 6>$null
$dataOutput = 
  Start-Job { Write-Host 'Some status message'; 42 } |
    Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

# Use ConvertTo-Json to surface the additional properties the output
# object is decorated with; you'll see something like:
# { 
#   "value": 42,
#   "PSComputerName": "localhost",
#   "RunspaceId": "ba1c0710-cb55-4759-81a2-2b089edd92a7",
#   "PSShowComputerName": false,
#   "PSSourceJobInstanceId": "44422412-6bc2-4b0d-8379-ddd09b2d8e56"
# }
$dataOutput | ConvertTo-Json
```

If you want to collect and emit output for each job separately:

```sh
$jobs = { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } | ForEach-Object { Start-Job $_ } 

# Wait for all jobs to complete.
$jobs | Wait-Job

# Collect the output for each job separately.
# You'll see the following:
#   VERBOSE: Output from job {  1, 2  }
#   1
#   2
#   VERBOSE: Output from job {  3, 4  }
#   3
#   4
$jobs | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "Output from job { $($_.Command) }"
  $_ | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
}
```

Comment: If I had to run code in each start-job before invoking my command, how would I ignore its console output (don't want it in the returned array)?

Comment: @jsnoobie See if my update (bottom section) helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. According to your example, you're providing one element at a time to the ForEach. But, if I am going to use foreach like this, then I'd have to pass an array of commands. I tried this:
$results = $cmds | ForEach-Object {Start-Job $_} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
and got *"Start-Job : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."* twice. How do I provide an array/list of strings as cmds?

Comment: $results = @("{1}","{2}") | ForEach-Object {Start-Job $_} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

Comment: @jsnoobie The first command shows how to convert _string_ commands into _script blocks_. My examples simply use array _literals_ as the input, but there's no difference from providing an array stored in a variable: in both cases, the array elements are sent _one by one_ to `ForEach-Object`, which is a must, given that `Start-Job` only accepts _one_ `-ScriptBlock` argument at a time. Outputting an array (enumerable) to the success output stream / pipeline _enumerates_ it, by design. This is a fundamental PowerShell feature.

Comment: It seems weird to me `Receive-Job` has to come after the loop, not after the job itself. Can I do `{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } | ForEach-Object { Start-Job {$_} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob }` instead? I've tried that, and the output appears the same. Also, is `Receive-Job` necessary at all? Will the jobs not run unless it's used?

Comment: @gargoylebident, I assume you meant `Start-Job $_`, not `Start-Job {$_}` - yes, that works. Yes, with multiple jobs receiving and waiting right away can be useful, but only with a _single_ `Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove` call, applied to _all_ jobs: `{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } | ForEach-Object { Start-Job $_ } |  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob` Otherwise, there's no parallel execution.

Comment: @gargoylebident, no, `Receive-Job` isn't strictly necessary; the job runs to completion on its own, unless you exit the calling session beforehand. However, you'll want to at least ensure that it completed, which you can do in the abstract with `$job.State -eq 'Completed'` - but non-terminating errors may still have occurred, which you'll only see with `Receive-Job`.